# How to install grype in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation, docker

I want to install [Grype](https://github.com/anchore/grype) in windows 10 but finding it difficult to [install](https://github.com/anchore/grype#installation) as directed. It will be helpfull if get the installation process of grype in windows 10. After installation i want to run `grype <image> --scope all-layers` this command to find out vulnerabilities of docker image.

Comment: What step are you stuck on?  You will want to use WSL2 obviously

Comment: the instructions are for linux or os-x. They won't translate directly to windows.

Comment: Im stuck here: brew tap anchore/grype

Comment: what can i use instead of 'brew' in windows?

Comment: brew  is a way to package the software for OSX. I *guess* you might be able to run the  linux install process in WSL, but I have no idea if WSL can check on 'windows' docker containers. If you're trying to run brew on windows though, you might want to learn a bit about what these commands are and what you are doing first before vulnerability scanning things.

Comment: Consider installing Kali Linux as a virtual machine. Grype installs there:  https://kalilinuxtutorials.com/grype/

Comment: "brew tap anchore/grype" - only works on macOS.  You can't use it on Windows. You can use the Linux instructions on Windows provided you use WSL2.  Have you tried that?  You can't run a macOS only command on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Can be installed via wsl 2 for windows 10
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux

(i've found it better personally than the docker version, being about 30-40% quicker but that could just be my local machine)

Instructions:

1. install wsl 2 for windows 10

   more info: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10
2. install grype via script in wsl 2, to a local mounted directory

   ```
   curl -sSfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anchore/grype/main/install.sh | sh -s -- -b /mnt/c/xxx

   # in my case /mnt/c/dev/bin/grype/ === "C:\dev\bin\grype"
   curl -sSfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anchore/grype/main/install.sh | sh -s -- -b /mnt/c/dev/bin/grype/
   ```

   more info: https://github.com/anchore/grype#installation
3. add the path you installed grype into, into your PATH (for me that was "C:\dev\bin\grype")

   more info: https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/
4. open up grype in wsl 2 linux on windows

Result:

```
local@DESKTOP-GPVF0RR:~$ grype version
Application:          grype
Version:              0.13.0
BuildDate:            2021-06-02T01:57:12Z
GitCommit:            3d21b8397d65770d292184b09a4f676bce6f3ec8
GitTreeState:         clean
Platform:             linux/amd64
GoVersion:            go1.16.4
Compiler:             gc
Supported DB Schema:  3
```

with scan

```
local@DESKTOP-GPVF0RR:~$ grype python --scope all-layers
 ✔ Vulnerability DB        [updated]
 ✔ Parsed image
 ✔ Cataloged packages      [1349 packages]
 ✔ Scanned image           [4054 vulnerabilities]
NAME                          INSTALLED                     FIXED-IN               VULNERABILITY     SEVERITY
apt                           1.8.2.3                                              CVE-2011-3374     Negligible
bash                          5.0-4                                                CVE-2019-18276    Negligible
binutils                      2.31.1-16                                            CVE-2018-18483    Negligible
....
```