# I installed grype on my Windows 10 machine, but my WSL2 console does not seem to detect it. What have I done wrong?

Tags: windows-10, terminal, path, console

I installed Grype through a command I ran in WSL2 and I believe I correctly added it to PATH.
When I try and use Grype in my terminal however, nothing happens.

[image: Grype in the folder]

I added "C:\grype" to PATH.

[image: WSL2 not recognising grype]

My WSL2 Ubuntu terminal does not recognise grype.

Comment: Your screenshot indicates you’re attempting to run it in a command prompt not within Bash (WSL). WSL doesn’t have access to that particular directory

Comment: The application absolutely cannot run on Windows. It might run on WSL distribution but I doubt it. So your question is confusing since it’s not designed to perform a vulnerability scan on Windows so adding it to PATH makes no sense

Comment: [Edit] your question to indicate what command you used to install the application.  The error you receive is an indication you are attempting to run a Linux application within Windows.  Which isn't possible outside of WSL2, even then your not running a Linux application on Windows, you are running a Linux application within a WSL2 environment which itself is a Linux environment running on what is essentially an integrated VM.

Comment: I guess I've misunderstood how Grype works then, but in this post (https://superuser.com/questions/1634774/how-to-install-grype-in-windows-10) it is explained to work in the way I've been trying to get it to.

Comment: I will again point out that, your screenshots indicate you are trying to run a linux/amd64 executable, within Windows not WSL2.  Which is the reason you got the error you received.  If you actually ran it in WSL2, and you received a different error, document that error.  Grype  is not a Windows executable. You should [edit] your question to eliminate your attempts to run it within Windows, and instead focus, on running it within WSL2.  To be clear, it's only compatible with WSl2, it is not compatible with WSl1.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Navigate to the folder that contains the executable you want to run within WSL.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to able to use the Path for this because Windows programs can only run Windows executables. WSL let's you run Linux applications inside Windows, but it does not allow programs on Windows to use non-Windows executables.

You can access Grype from in Windows from INSIDE WSL, but not outside it.

You will need to rethink why and how you're trying to access Grype.